# Find the minimum date by user and add it as a boolean column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have

```
SELECT 
    id, email, voucher_id, created_at_reservation, reservation_id
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM users
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              status, user_id, voucher_id, 
              created_at AS created_at_reservation, id AS reservation_id
          FROM 
              reservations 
          WHERE 
              reservations.status = 'paid') AS r ON r.user_id = users.id) AS u
```

And I want the minimum `u.created_at_reservation` by `u.id`, I would like to have a new column that is `TRUE` if that row contains the minimum `u.created_at_reservation` for that `u.id`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using some ancient DBMS, it's probably easiest to use a window function:

```
SELECT id, email, voucher_id, created_at_reservation, reservation_id
     , MIN(created_at_reservation) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as min_reservation  
[...]
```

For the boolean column you can add another outermost level:

```
SELECT ..., created_at_reservation = min_reservation as new_col
FROM (  
   SELECT id, email, voucher_id, created_at_reservation, reservation_id
     , MIN(created_at_reservation) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as min_reservation  
   [...]
)
```